# Inserting text into a JTextPane without a newline

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jtextpane

For awhile now, I've been trying to insert a character, sorta like auto-completion in Eclipse into a JTextPane with the following code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class Main implements Runnable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final int WIDTH = 800;
private static final int HEIGHT = 600;
private static final String NAME = "";
private JFrame frame;
private JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

public void run()
{
    frame = new JFrame(NAME);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    frame.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    textPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    textPane.setEditable(true);
    textPane.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                    ArrayList<Integer> keyCode = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument(); 
                    keyCode.add(arg0.getKeyCode());
                    if(keyCode.contains(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET)) /* If an open brace has been hit! */
                    {
                        if(keyCode.contains(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT)) /* Because brackets and braces use the same keyCode, we needed to 
                                                                 * make sure it was a brace */
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                doc.insertString(textPane.getCaretPosition(), "\n}", null); /* Putting in our new string */
                            } catch(Exception e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return;
                        }
                        /* Auto-complete it */
                        try
                        {
                            doc.insertString(textPane.getCaretPosition(), "]", null); /* Putting in our new string */
                        } catch(Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
    });
    frame.pack(); 
    frame.setVisible(true);



}

public void start()
{
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public final static void main(String args[])
{
    new Main().start();
}
```

}

The only issue I'm having with this, is that it seems as though the offset in insertString is rows, instead of columns; for instance, when I try to set the offest of insertString to 0, it places the character *behind* the typed character, so it ends up looking somthing like this:

```
)(
```

Instead of my desired output of this:

```
()
```

However, if I set the offset to 1, then it goes down an entire row, making it look like:

```
(
)
```

I can't figure out what's going on here, or any other way to insert text *besides* using setText.

Any ideas? Am I doomed to only use setText? Thanks for all of your time!

~Cent

Edit:

Changed code to a SSCCE.

Comment: is it about parenthesis '(' or square brackets '['? I dont understand from where new line comes, did you try to remove VK_SHIFT condition block? offset should work on row. Can you provide sample working code with this problem to try?

Comment: @vishal_aim: It's whenever I try to complete anything that I'm getting this error, and I don't now where it's coming from either. I have tried to remove the VK_SHIFT condition, but it didn't do anything. Also, I changed the code to a SSCCE.

Comment: @StanislavL: Changed the posted code to a SSCCE.